# Python Unittest structure

Tags: python, python-unittest

So in my project I have a long (~1000 lines)`TestCase` module with only 1 TestCase.
I want to divide it into 3-4 separate TestCase modules (separate files).
But how can I make a **common** `setUp` **to share fixtures** for all modules?
Use some import fixtures?
I use `setUpClass` in that my long module with a single TestCase.
Pls, advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is define a parent class, e.g.

```
class CommonTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUpClass(self):
        # Do setup or anything else here
```

and then in other files or cases you can use inheritance to use the same setup steps from parent class `CommonTestCase`:

```
from my_package import CommonTestCase

class MyTestCaseA(CommonTestCase):
    def test_this(self):
        # Test implementation

class MyTestCaseB(CommonTestCase):
    def test_that(self):
        # Test implementation
```

Comment: Looks good, but what if just insert setUpClass method in CommonTestCase instead of set fixtures in __init__? Is it same?

Comment: @ruslanway I would say using `setUpClass` is _preferred_. In my opinion there is no need whatsoever to override `TestCase.__init__`.

Comment: Absolutely, it's functionally the same. In a project I pulled this from `__init__` was used to set some variables and it was a clean solution, however I will modify the answer to reduce any misconceptions.